# Unable to Remove a Project from Project View in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I have a project sitting in my Project Explorer window in Eclipse that just won't go away.

- If I right-click on the project and select "Delete" (or do anything else, for that matter, such as rename...), I get the following error:

  null argument:transferRule without beginRule
- If I delete the project folder from the workspace and restart Eclipse, it *still* shows in the Project Explorer when I reopen Eclipse.

Here is the output of .log in the .metadata folder from my workspace:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-09-19 01:02:22.099
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommandInContext(LegacyHandlerService.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.actions.LTKLauncher.runCommand(LTKLauncher.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.actions.LTKLauncher.openDeleteWizard(LTKLauncher.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.DeleteResourceAction.run(DeleteResourceAction.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.BaseSelectionListenerAction.runWithEvent(BaseSelectionListenerAction.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1392)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3742)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3363)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.FormToolkit$BorderPainter.paintControl(FormToolkit.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1392)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1416)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1401)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.gtk_expose_event(Control.java:3165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.gtk_expose_event(Composite.java:726)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowProc(Widget.java:2090)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:5467)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4569)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._gtk_main_do_event(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.gtk_main_do_event(OS.java:8756)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.eventProc(Display.java:1243)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._g_main_context_iteration(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.g_main_context_iteration(OS.java:2302)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.setVisible(Shell.java:2159)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.open(Shell.java:1546)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation$1.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.actions.DeleteResourcesHandler.execute(DeleteResourcesHandler.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor92.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    ... 41 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 4 10000 2014-09-19 01:02:23.136
!MESSAGE Internal Error
!STACK 0
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardDialog2.run(RefactoringWizardDialog2.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard.internalPerformFinish(RefactoringWizard.java:637)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.UserInputWizardPage.performFinish(UserInputWizardPage.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.resource.DeleteResourcesWizard$DeleteResourcesRefactoringConfigurationPage.performFinish(DeleteResourcesWizard.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard.performFinish(RefactoringWizard.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardDialog2.okPressed(RefactoringWizardDialog2.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.buttonPressed(Dialog.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1392)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3742)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3363)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: null argument:transferRule without beginRule
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.ImplicitJobs.transfer(ImplicitJobs.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobManager.transferRule(JobManager.java:1549)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.threadChange(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.invokeThreadListener(ModalContext.java:442)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:383)
    ... 35 more
Root exception:
org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: null argument:transferRule without beginRule
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.ImplicitJobs.transfer(ImplicitJobs.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobManager.transferRule(JobManager.java:1549)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.threadChange(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.invokeThreadListener(ModalContext.java:442)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardDialog2.run(RefactoringWizardDialog2.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard.internalPerformFinish(RefactoringWizard.java:637)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.UserInputWizardPage.performFinish(UserInputWizardPage.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.resource.DeleteResourcesWizard$DeleteResourcesRefactoringConfigurationPage.performFinish(DeleteResourcesWizard.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard.performFinish(RefactoringWizard.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardDialog2.okPressed(RefactoringWizardDialog2.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.buttonPressed(Dialog.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1392)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3742)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3363)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.debug.core 4 2 2014-09-19 01:02:27.959
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.debug.core".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core.server.internal.DelegatingServerBehavior.setModulesStopped(DelegatingServerBehavior.java:123)
    at org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core.server.internal.DelegatingServerBehavior.setModulesStopped(DelegatingServerBehavior.java:130)
    at org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core.server.internal.DelegatingServerBehavior.setServerStopped(DelegatingServerBehavior.java:119)
    at org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core.server.internal.v7.DelegatingJBoss7ServerBehavior.setServerStopped(DelegatingJBoss7ServerBehavior.java:156)
    at org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core.server.internal.v7.DelegatingJBoss7ServerBehavior$JBossServerLifecycleListener.handleDebugEvents(DelegatingJBoss7ServerBehavior.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugPlugin$EventNotifier.run(DebugPlugin.java:1132)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugPlugin$EventNotifier.dispatch(DebugPlugin.java:1166)
    at org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugPlugin$EventDispatchJob.run(DebugPlugin.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.debug.core 4 125 2014-09-19 01:02:27.960
!MESSAGE An exception occurred while dispatching debug events.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core.server.internal.DelegatingServerBehavior.setModulesStopped(DelegatingServerBehavior.java:123)
    at org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core.server.internal.DelegatingServerBehavior.setModulesStopped(DelegatingServerBehavior.java:130)
    at org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core.server.internal.DelegatingServerBehavior.setServerStopped(DelegatingServerBehavior.java:119)
    at org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core.server.internal.v7.DelegatingJBoss7ServerBehavior.setServerStopped(DelegatingJBoss7ServerBehavior.java:156)
    at org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core.server.internal.v7.DelegatingJBoss7ServerBehavior$JBossServerLifecycleListener.handleDebugEvents(DelegatingJBoss7ServerBehavior.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugPlugin$EventNotifier.run(DebugPlugin.java:1132)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugPlugin$EventNotifier.dispatch(DebugPlugin.java:1166)
    at org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugPlugin$EventDispatchJob.run(DebugPlugin.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
!SESSION 2014-09-19 01:02:33.312 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_AU
Framework arguments:  -application org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench -product com.jboss.jbds.product.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -application org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench -product com.jboss.jbds.product.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-09-19 01:02:37.440
!MESSAGE Unable to find Action Set: ajrefactoring

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-09-19 01:02:37.443
!MESSAGE Unable to find Action Set: org.eclipse.contribution.xref.ui.XRefActionSet

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-09-19 01:02:37.444
!MESSAGE Unable to find Action Set: org.eclipse.mylyn.context.ui.actionSet

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-09-19 01:02:37.444
!MESSAGE Unable to find Action Set: org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.navigation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-09-19 01:02:37.445
!MESSAGE Unable to find Action Set: org.springframework.ide.eclipse.aop.ui.ActionSet

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-09-19 01:02:37.445
!MESSAGE Unable to find Action Set: org.springframework.ide.eclipse.aop.ui.matcher.actionSet

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-09-19 01:02:37.446
!MESSAGE Unable to find Action Set: org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui.actionSet

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-09-19 01:02:37.446
!MESSAGE Unable to find Action Set: org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.search.actionSet

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-09-19 01:02:37.447
!MESSAGE Unable to find Action Set: org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.launch.actionSet

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-09-19 01:02:37.447
!MESSAGE Unable to find Action Set: ajelementCreation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2014-09-19 01:02:39.435
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "reload maven project".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.configureExecutionRequest(ProjectRegistryManager.java:817)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.createExecutionContext(ProjectRegistryManager.java:903)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.execute(ProjectRegistryManager.java:897)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.readProjectWithDependencies(ProjectRegistryManager.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.create(ProjectRegistryManager.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.MavenProjectManager.create(MavenProjectManager.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.actions.SelectionUtil.getMavenProject(SelectionUtil.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.editor.pom.MavenPomEditor.readMavenProject(MavenPomEditor.java:754)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.editor.pom.MavenPomEditor$6.run(MavenPomEditor.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 4 4 2014-09-19 01:02:40.775
!MESSAGE can not calculate a model ID without a document reference
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can not calculate a model ID without a document reference
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.FileBufferModelManager.calculateId(FileBufferModelManager.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.ModelManagerImpl._getModelFor(ModelManagerImpl.java:614)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.ModelManagerImpl.getModelForRead(ModelManagerImpl.java:1442)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.editing.PomEdits.performOnDOMDocument(PomEdits.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.editor.pom.MavenPomEditorPage.updateParentAction(MavenPomEditorPage.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.editor.pom.MavenPomEditorPage.createFormContent(MavenPomEditorPage.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.editor.pom.OverviewPage.createFormContent(OverviewPage.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormPage$1.run(FormPage.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormPage.createPartControl(FormPage.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.pageChange(FormEditor.java:471)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.editor.pom.MavenPomEditor.pageChange(MavenPomEditor.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.setActivePage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:1083)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.setActivePage(FormEditor.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.editor.pom.MavenPomEditor.setActivePage(MavenPomEditor.java:1048)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.editor.pom.MavenPomEditor.selectActivePage(MavenPomEditor.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.editor.pom.MavenPomEditor.addPages(MavenPomEditor.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.createPages(FormEditor.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:323)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:877)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:857)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:949)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1147)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:649)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveRenderer.processContents(PerspectiveRenderer.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can delete this pesky project?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a full stacktrace for the 'null argument' error in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory?

Comment: Thanks.  I added the stacktrace from .log in the question.

Comment: The log looks a bit of a mess. It may be safer to create a new workspace and import the other projects in to that.

Comment: Thanks greg-449, I'll just do that. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

My solution is remove this file .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi